# Append Hidden field into DIV container,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dropzone.js

I have a jQuery image upload tool which displays the uploaded files into a div container. I want to attach a hidden field with field values to each rendered images to the div container,

here is the javascript code

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: 'upload',
            dataType: 'json',
            add: function (e, data) {
                data.submit();
            },
            success:function(response,status) {
                console.log(response.filename);
                var filePath = 'static/uploads/' + response.filename;
                var img = $('<img />', {
                    src: filePath
                });
                img.appendTo($('#Thumb'));
                $('#filePath').val(filePath);
                console.log('success');
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

here is the current div layout,

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="txtPost">Photos</label>

<div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                        Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="file" multiple>
                    </span>
                </span>
        <div class="container" id="Thumb">
<input type="hidden" name="filePath" id="filePath"></input>
        </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

Currently

```
var img = $('<img />', {
                        src: filePath
                    });
                    img.appendTo($('#Thumb'));
```

is able to add the image source into the div layout, i want to do the same for the hidden input type too to append to the same element id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this do it

```
var img = $('<img />', {
    src: filePath
});
img.appendTo($('#Thumb'));

var inp = $('<input type="hidden" />', {
    value: 'some value of yours'
});
inp.appendTo($('#Thumb'));
```